# preg_replace and gettext problem

Tags: php, gettext

My project has templates with HTML. In order to ease the localization, I have added a preffix and suffix in all things I want to be translated of the HTML templates. Since I can't use `_()` inside HTML, I do a replace before showing the template:

```
preg_replace("%\<t\>([a-zA-Z0-9\.\\s)]*)\</t\>%is",_("$1"),$template);
```

I replaced `_()` with my `tr()` translating function and apparently it gets hit, just cant find the translation i guess.

When I use `print _('same text');` it shows up correctly.

```
preg_replace("%\<t\>([a-zA-Z0-9\.\\s)]*)\</t\>%is",_("hello"),$template);
```

So i'm guessing there's some issue locating the translations while using `preg_replace` like that.

I'm not looking for alternatives to storing the data, I'm looking for a solution to this problem if you have any.

Comment: Most of the backslashes in your regex are redundant. You only need `\.` and `\s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_replace_callback` or the `/e` (eval - and it has a reason why it sounds like evil!) modifier of `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 1):

your calling the gettext function before the preg_replace has fired, you need to allow the PCRE library to call the function for you, if your using PHP5+ then try this:

```
preg_replace_callback("%\<t\>([a-zA-Z0-9\.\\s)]*)\</t\>%is",function($matches){
    return $matches[1];
},$template);
```

Comment: s/PHP5/PHP5.3/ (no closures/anonymous functions in earlier versions)